# NOC for 1 year student visa. Is it reasonable?

Tags: student-visa, schengen, spain

I work for a company in the software industry. I've been admitted to a Spanish university and I am currently applying for a student visa. The duration of the study program is 1 year. One of the required document is:

> - A letter from the workplace explaining the employee leave date and the leave approval from the company.

I guess that this document is the No Objection Certificate (NOC).

While I can understand the NOC for a tourist visa or short term visa, I find it unreasonable to ask the company I'm working in to give me NOC for a whole 1 year. Is my reasoning correct ? Should I try to get the NOC anyway or ignore this requirement ?

Comment: If it’s ‘required’ then surely you don’t have a choice but to supply it or risk a refusal?

Comment: @Traveller Some requirements can be tolerated. For example they are asking for a proof of accommodation for the whole study duration while some people managed to get the visa with reservation for the first month only.

Comment: Well I’m not sure why you’re asking the question, in that case? Or why you think it’s unreasonable to ask your employer to confirm in writing something they’ve agreed to?

Comment: Is it reasonable to ask for 1 year leave ? I may ask my employer for it but is this really reasonable ? I also think of asking my employer for a letter confirming my employment state (if they didn't agree to approve 1 year leave).

Comment: Some employers give extended leave for study. It will depend on your employment T&C and their internal policies, I imagine. If they don’t agree then you’ll need to resign in order to take up the university place, which would mean the letter confirming your employment state would be rather meaningless.

Comment: @Traveller I got your point. Regarding the employment letter it won't be totally meaningless. It will show that I have a job in my country so I'm not applying for a visa just to work illegally. Note that I'll not resign unless the visa is granted so I'll be still employed in the time of visa application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important factor here is honesty and giving a clear overview of your status. If your work can give you a NOC then present it. Otherwise show them the proof of employment and let them decide.

What happened with me is that I showed them the proof of employment and the salary slips. The officer asked me if I would leave this job to study in this program and I replied yes. That's all about this point and thankfully I got the visa!